# PHP, SPL predefined constants

Tags: php, reference, constants, spl

where can i get some references about `SPL predefined constants` like `SELF_FIRST`,`CHILD_FIRST` ? on [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.constants.php) i don't get much(just their type).

Comment: my guess is that these constants are used by the RucursiveIterator "internaly". You need references to do what if i may ask?

Comment: that's right @andreas, i've seen an example of recursiveIterator and then started to read about SPL. After i covered a good part i noticed that i didn't get any explanation of those constants(what they mean and how to use them)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'll outline (some of) the class constants from the [page you linked to](http://php.net/spl.constants) then raise a few other points.

### RecursiveIteratorIterator iteration modes

---

The `RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY` iteration mode. (This is the *default* mode.)

This iteration mode (one of three) restricts the items available during iteration to only the "leaves" (think of a recursive structure as a tree with a series of branches sprouting other branches or, in the case of no more branches, having leaves on the end).  In the array `array('a'=>array('b','c'),'d','e'=>array('f','g'))` the leaves are `b`,`c`,`d`,`f` and `g` since they are at the end, they do not sprout any more items.

To give a code snippet showing this mode in action (There will be a series of examples having the same recursive array iterator with a recursive iterator iterator using different modes and flags):

```
$array = array('a'=>array('b','c'),'d','e'=>array('f','g'));
$ait   = new RecursiveArrayIterator($array);

// Only iterate over leaves
$rit   = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($ait, RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY);
foreach ($rit as $item) {
    echo $item;
}
// Output: bcdfg
```

---

The `RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST` iteration mode.

This iteration mode instructs the iterator that the "parent" items (i.e. not leaves) are to be placed before their children (if any) when iterating.

```
// Parents come first
$rit   = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($ait, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach ($rit as $key => $item) {
    if (is_array($item)) echo "[$key]"; // parent
    else echo $item;                    // child
}
// Output: [a]bcd[e]fg
```

---

The `RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST` iteration mode.

This iteration mode swaps around the parent/child positions such that the children items (leaves) come first, followed by the parent as demonstrated by:

```
// Children first
$rit   = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($ait, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
foreach ($rit as $key => $item) {
    if (is_array($item)) echo "[$key]"; // parent
    else echo $item;                    // child
}
// Output: bc[a]dfg[e]
```

---

### Other points

**RecursiveIteratorIterator constructor flags**

Those are only the constants for the three modes (leaves only, parent first or child first) of iterating over recursive iterators. The RecursiveIteratorIterator also has a `flags` argument which affects other behaviour like whether to halt if a child object throws an Exception, whether to call `__toString` for the items, etc. (the flags are `CachingIterator` constants, which are equally undocumented).

**Other SPL constants**

This ties in with my next point. There is no single, one-stop spot which lists all of the constants available throughout the SPL: most of the classes do not even list their own constants. You can however use [reflection](http://php.net/reflection) to take a peek at available constants. On the command line use something like `php --rc recursiveiteratoriterator | grep -i constant` to see a list of the RecursiveIteratorIterator's constants.

**Lack of documentation**

The documentation available in the PHP manual is written (pretty much) entirely by volunteers. The SPL in particular is a sore spot with there still being a huge amount of work to do before that area is ship-shape and up-to-standard.  If anyone wants to help in that (not sure if SO would consider this advertising?) then contact me (salathe@php.net) or sign up to the PHP documentation mailing list (send a blank email to phpdoc-subscribe@lists.php.net) and get stuck in. The more, the merrier.

Comment: thanks @salathe , this is exactly what i was looking for and even more detailed than i've expected. great post!

Comment: +1 Great answer. But there's an error in the SELF_FIRST bit. // Parents come first
$rit   = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($ait, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST); should be SELF_FIRST

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [SPL files](http://php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/files.html) at http://php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/.

Comment: like i said, i found the predefined constants page on php.net but all i get is their type

Comment: @kmunky: Well, to get their value, you can simply use `echo RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY;`

Comment: ok..now i know their values...but i don't know their meanings :D

Comment: @kmunky: The constants of *RecursiveIteratorIterator* are to be used for the constructor of that class (see http://php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/classRecursiveIteratorIterator.html#e831f5147ec06773875b31544c95d66c). There you can find a description of these constants. Pretty much the same applies to the constants of *CachingIterator*.